# Using property values in schedule trigger - Cruisecontrol.Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I'm setting up CCNet to build our projects at specific intervals.

The current setting is to do integration builds throughout the day at specific time and do perform a deployment build in between the integration builds. I would like to use only one project as to track the modifications.

Below is my sample xml file i'm including in ccnet.config

```
<triggers>
  <parameterTrigger>
    <trigger
      type ="scheduleTrigger"
      time="15:00"
      buildCondition="IfModificationExists"> 
      <weekDays>
        <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Wednesday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Friday</weekDay>
      </weekDays>
    </trigger>
    <Parameters>
      <namedValue
        name="BuildRelease"
        value="fullCI-without-deployment" />
    </Parameters>
  </parameterTrigger>
</triggers>
```

.....

```
<tasks>
  <nant>
    <executable>D:\source\Build\nant-0.85\bin\Nant.exe</executable>
    <buildFile>D:\source\Build\nantfile.build</buildFile>
    <nologo>true</nologo>
    <targetList>
      <target>"$[BuildRelease]"</target>
    </targetList>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>4500</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  </nant>
  <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound ="true" />
</tasks>
```

This doesn't seem to work for some reason. May be I should specify the property in a different way? As you can see, I would like to add another scheduleTrigger with different property value for deployment builds.

Thanks for your help
Sanjeev

Comment: Nope. No errors. It just doesn't work. I had already spent enough time trying different ways to use a dynamic property from a trigger with no luck. Temporally falling back to use two different projects, one for builds and one for deployment

Answer (score 0):

I get the expected results when using `parameters` with a small `p` instead of a capital one. Please try…